# Using shell script to extract data based on user input

Tags: text-processing, scripting

```
eid|location|desg|status
001|india|hr|active
002|delhi|marketing|inactive
003|hyderabad|sales|active
004|Bangalore|admin|inactive
```

The data is in the above format, delimiter is '|'
Prompt should ask for the eid and display the status as active or inactive.

```
please enter eid: 001
status is : active
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This seems like a reasonably straightforward job with `awk`

Comment: @Eric ... or with `sed` or with `grep` and `cut` or with ...

Comment: This isn't a free script writing service. We're here to help *you* do your work, not do it for you. Try doing this and ask a question here if a *specific* part of it is giving you trouble.

Comment: what if i want to search the eid present in for multiple files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `read` and `sed`

```
read -p "enter an eid: "; sed -n "/$REPLY/ s/.*|\(.*\)/status: \1/p" file
```

#### Notes

- `/$REPLY/` find a line with the user input
- `-n` only print the lines we ask for
- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `|\(.*\)` save any characters after the last `|` to reference later with `\1`
- `p` print the modified line

To query the newest file:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *; do
  if [[ "$f" -nt "$newest" ]]; then
    "$f"="$newest"
  fi
done
read -p "enter an eid: "
sed -n "/$REPLY/ s/.*|\(.*\)/status: \1/p" "$newest"
```

Credit to [@terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) for finding me [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099?highlight=%28oldest%29) - because we know `ls -t | head -n 1` is not OK

Comment: what if i want to search multiple files

Comment: Thank you for your answer it really helped me. What if i want to search multiple files in the same directory based on file created timestamp, please help.

Comment: `sed` will take multiple file arguments (you can put `*` to search all files in the current working directory, for example). But I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean by timestamp - you want to look in the 5 most recent files or something like that?

Comment: timestamp means like log files created continuously, it should search the latest file created.

Comment: @vijayraju ok, I've edited my answer :)

Comment: thank you it worked, one more help please. what it i want to read more than two files and display the results.

Comment: @vijayraju as mentioned, `sed` takes multiple file arguments `sed 'commands' file1 file2 file3` or `file*` for all files whose names begin with `file`...

Answer (score 3):

This does the parsing in `sh`:

```
printf 'Enter eid: ' >&2
read query

while IFS="|" read eid location desg status; do
   if [ "$eid" = "$query" ]; then
      printf 'Status is "%s"\n' "$status"
      break
   fi
done <data.in
```

This is assuming that your data file is called `data.in`.